# Como capturar mais de um atributo a partir de uma chave estrangeira?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou fazendo um projeto Java-Desktop de Locação de Veículos.
Estou usando MVC, DAO e JDBC.

No meu banco tenho as tabelas Locacao e Carro:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `frota`.`carro` (
  `idcarro` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chassi` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `renavam` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `placa` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `combustivel` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_de_portas` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cor` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `quilometragem` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_locacao` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `marca` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modelo` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcarro`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 19
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `frota`.`locacao` (
  `idlocacao` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fkcodcarro` INT(11) NULL,
  `fkcodcliente` INT(11) NULL,
  `fkcodfuncionario` INT(11) NULL,
  `data_locacao` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_locacao` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_devolucao` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_devolucao` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tempo` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `taxa` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlocacao`),
  INDEX `fk_locacao_funcionario1_idx` (`fkcodfuncionario` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_locacao_cliente1_idx` (`fkcodcliente` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_locacao_carro1_idx` (`fkcodcarro` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_locacao_carro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fkcodcarro`)
    REFERENCES `frota`.`carro` (`idcarro`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_locacao_cliente1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fkcodcliente`)
    REFERENCES `frota`.`cliente` (`idcliente`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_locacao_funcionario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fkcodfuncionario`)
    REFERENCES `frota`.`funcionario` (`idfuncionario`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 15
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Minha intenção é gravar no banco na tabela Locacao. Sei que tenho que utilizar a chave de estrangeira de carro(fkcodcarro) de alguma forma, já pesquisei e tentei fazer de diversas maneiras mas sempre continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Adicione o erro na sua resposta, nos ajuda a entender o que esta acontecendo

Comment: O que você quis dizer com 'capturar mais de um atributo a partir....'? Qual é o erro que você esta recebendo? Como você esta tentando fazer esse insert?  Edite a sua questão e poste isso tudo.

Comment: Meu chefe, creio que você terá que realizar um Select de acordo com a FK do Carro e recuperar esses valores, mas, isso não é ideal. Qual sentido de se fazer isso?

Comment: Gnt o erro é esse: Cannot add or update a child row : a foreign key constraint fails ('frota'.'locacao'), CONSTRAINT 'fk_locacao_carro1' FOREIGN KEY ('fkcodcarro') REFERENCES 'carro'('idcarro'))

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas propriedades que todos os bancos de dados relacionais devem respeitar, são as propriedades ACID:

- Atomicidade: todos os passos de uma transação devem ocorrer. Se um passo não ocorre, nenhum outro ocorre.
- Consistência: todos os clientes enxergam o mesmo resultado após uma transação.
- Isolamento: uma transação deve ocorrer sem efeitos colaterais.
- Durabilidade: o resultado de uma transação é persistido.

Dessa maneira, eu creio que a transação que você está utilizando para inserir uma linha na tabela `locacao` está rompendo alguma dessas propriedades. Para checar em qual o ponto está o erro, vale se fazer as seguintes perguntas:

- Estou tentando inserir algo nulo em um campo com restrição `NOT NULL`?
- Estou tentando inserir um tipo de dado em algum campo que não é compatível com esse tipo?
- Estou violando alguma restrição de chave-primária? Prestar atenção nos valores que são `AUTO INCREMENT`
- Estou violando alguma restrição de chave-estrangeira? Verificar se a chave estrangeira da linha que você quer inserir corresponde a um registro que realmente existe na table estrangeira.

Espero que esses pontos ajudem a descobrir onde está seu erro.

Comment: Pelo que entendi meu erro deve ser violação de chave estrangeira. Poi acontece isso: Cannot add or update a child row : a foreign key constraint fails ('frota'.'locacao'), CONSTRAINT 'fk_locacao_carro1' FOREIGN KEY ('fkcodcarro') REFERENCES 'carro'('idcarro'))

Comment: Bianca, então você está tentando adicionar um idcarro que não tem uma linha correspondente na tabela carro

Comment: olha a minha tabela carro está preenchida tem 3 registros nela.